# Error converting numerical array to sparse

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am working on a huge data set and I have issues converting a numerical array to sparse.

```
import pandas as pd
l = pd.read_csv('merge_from_ofoct.csv')
l.drop('Unnamed: 12', axis=1, inplace=True)
l.drop('CRS_ARR_TIME', axis=1, inplace=True)
l.drop('CRS_DEP_TIME', axis=1, inplace=True)
l = l[(l.T != 0).any()]
count_nan = len(l) - l.count()  #gives the no. of rows with no values in it
l_no_missing = l.dropna()  #Dropping the rows with missing values
f = l_no_missing  #final dataframe with no missing values
count_nan = len(f) - f.count()  #verifying if the missing vaules are removed
count_nan
airport_data = pd.read_csv('Airport_data.csv', 
                               header = 0) 
training.drop(training.columns[0], axis = 1, inplace = True)
f['CARRIER'] = f['UNIQUE_CARRIER']
f["CARRIER"] = pd.factorize(f["CARRIER"])[0]
CARRIER = f[['UNIQUE_CARRIER', 'CARRIER']].drop_duplicates()
training = f
training.drop('UNIQUE_CARRIER', axis = 1, inplace = True)
scalingDF = training[['DISTANCE']] # Numerical features
categDF = training[['MONTH', 'DAY_OF_MONTH', 'ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID', 
                   'DEST_AIRPORT_ID', 
                   'CARRIER', 'DAY_OF_WEEK']] # Categorical features


from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

encoder = OneHotEncoder() # Create encoder object
categDF_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(categDF) 

type(categDF_encoded) 
from scipy import sparse # Need this to create a sparse array
scalingDF_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(scalingDF) #can't convert numerical array to sparse
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 from scipy import sparse # Need this to create a sparse array
>   ----> 2 scalingDF_sparse = sparse.csr_matrix(scalingDF)
>
> /Users/nikhil_maladkar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.pyc
>   in **init**(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
>        67                         self.format)
>        68             from .coo import coo_matrix
>   ---> 69             self._set_self(self.**class**(coo_matrix(arg1, dtype=dtype)))
>        70 
>        71         # Read matrix dimensions given, if any
>
> /Users/nikhil_maladkar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.pyc
>   in **init**(self, arg1, shape, dtype, copy)
>        29                 arg1 = arg1.copy()
>        30             else:
>   ---> 31                 arg1 = arg1.asformat(self.format)
>        32             self._set_self(arg1)
>        33
>
> /Users/nikhil_maladkar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.pyc
>   in asformat(self, format)
>       218             return self
>       219         else:
>   --> 220             return getattr(self,'to' + format)()
>       221 
>       222     ###################################################################
>
> /Users/nikhil_maladkar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.pyc
>   in tocsr(self)
>       328             indptr = np.empty(M + 1, dtype=idx_dtype)
>       329             indices = np.empty(self.nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
>   --> 330             data = np.empty(self.nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype))
>       331 
>       332             coo_tocsr(M, N, self.nnz,
>
> /Users/nikhil_maladkar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/sputils.pyc
>   in upcast(*args)
>        55             return t
>        56 
>   ---> 57     raise TypeError('no supported conversion for types: %r' % (args,))
>        58 
>        59
>
> TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('O'),)

Comment: Something quick to try is changing: `categDF_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(categDF)` to `categDF_encoded = encoder.fit_transform(categDF.values)`. The TypeError you're receiving states that the encoder doesn't know how to convert an object datatype, which may be a result of passing a pandas dataframe to it.

Comment: i am able to convert the categorical data but i can't do the same on the numeric data